# Flaw in logic for 100 blue eyes/hats/buttons brain teaser?

Tags: logic, induction, puzzle

This famous puzzle is here: https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/math/a26564/solution-to-riddle-of-the-week-27/

https://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html

My question: Given n+1 people with blue eyes, the n+1 person will see that no one leaves/dies at the nth iteration and hence realizes that he has blue eyes. However, it appears to me you also need to prove that nobody will leave/die before the nth iteration. Is there something that I'm missing that means it's not required.

Comment: How could anybody leave before the $n$th night? Suppose someone did. Then, by symmetry, they all would since they all have the same information. Surely you see that's fallacious?

Comment: @DonThousand Makes sense, thanks. In my mind I was thinking about people leaving one at a time.

Comment: "However, it appears to me you also need to prove that nobody will leave/die before the nth iteration."  A good telling of the story does just that.  ANd I think this answer does do that.  For any $k$th night before the $n$th night everyone would see at least $k$ people with blue eyes and not be capable of figuring their eye color.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about this problem is that instead of each person having a unique perspective, **every single person** has the exact same thought process because they are, at least according to the problem, identical. This means that if one person can figure out that they have blue eyes, by definition, so can everyone else. Therefore, for any iteration before the $nth$ one, nobody will leave/die because they do not have enough information yet. Then on the $nth$ iteration, **everyone** will leave.